# Alternative Derivations of London Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity

One way of deriving the London equation is to set the canonical momentum to zero: $$\mathbf{p}=m\mathbf{v}-2e\mathbf{A}=0$$
A second approach is to take the Ginzburg-Landau equation for the current density $$\mathbf{J}=\frac{2e}{m}\textrm{Re}\left[\psi^{\ast}(-i\hbar\mathbf{\nabla}-2e\mathbf{A})\psi\right]$$ and set the macroscopic wavefunction $\psi$ to a constant. Provided we set $|\psi|^{2}=n$, where $n$ is the number density of Cooper pairs, we obtain the same result $$\mathbf{J}=-\frac{(2e)^{2}}{m}n\mathbf{A}$$ in each case.

I want to reconcile these two approaches. Specifically, I want to be able to show that choosing $\psi$ to be a constant in the Ginzburg-Landau theory implies that that canonical momentum should be zero. This seems like a simple task at the surface, but I can't seem to show it...

Comment: Isn't this obvious? If the $\psi$ is a constant, the canonical momentum is just $\frac{\hbar}{i} \nabla \psi=0$? or if you ask about something else?

Comment: @ChuanChen Canonical momentum would be $(\frac{\hbar}{i}\mathbf{\nabla}-2e\mathbf{A})\psi$... Second term is an issue.

Comment: Do you really set the canonical momentum to zero, or the superfluid velocity ? $v=0$ in your equation seems to work quite well. By the way, in a bulk superconductor, the orbital current is zero (i.e., the term $\Psi^{\ast}\nabla\Psi\propto v$, which corresponds to the velocity according to your notations).

Comment: @klgklm what you write down is the velocity.

Comment: @ChuanChen But isn't $\mathbf{p}=m\mathbf{v}-2e\mathbf{A}$ called the canonical momentum? Then I have just promoted the 'real momentum' part to an operator... I am confused. I guess this is just a mix up with definitions etc.

Comment: @klgklm yes, but $\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla$ is the real space representation of the canonical momentum $p$, not $v$.